# Getting the float numbers from this string (Python)

Tags: python, string, variables, floating-point, extract

I have a string in this format "[12.45,56.78]" , How to extract the float numbers and assign them in two different variables . newbie in python please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python

Comment: While we seem to be playing code golf... `x,y = map(float, re.findall('\d+\.\d+', s))`

Comment: `a,b = map(float, s.strip("[]").split(","))`

Comment: d = [float(e) for e in ("[12.45,56.78]")[1:-1].split(",")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to evaluate the string and convert to list and then unpack them into two variables. Example -

```
>>> import ast
>>> a,b = ast.literal_eval("[12.45,56.78]")
>>> a
12.45
>>> b
56.78
```

Answer (score 2):

or

```
x = "[12.45,56.78]"
myList= eval(x)

myList[0]
Out[1]: 12.45

myList[1]
Out[2]: 56.78
```